# Find a file in a collection of files

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to compare two directories of file names. I can make it work iterating through `$dir1` and looking up each file in `$dir2` but it is understandably "slow" for 500 files across a network.

I would like to capture all the files in a collection using `$files = gci $dir1`, iterate through `$dir2` and search the collection for each file.

I tried:

```
$files = gci $dir1
 gci $dir2 | foreach {
   if ($files -contains $_) {
      echo "found" }
   }
```

and, of course, this was too easy.

What is the best way to do this search in a reasonably speedy way?

After reading @Mathias answer I switched from using `Select Name` to `gci $dir1 -Name` and now the contains works. Of course this changes the question since I am no longer dealing with a collection of file objects, just strings. 
Since I'm looking for missing files in $dir2, the final code looks like this:

```
$files = gci $dir2 -name
$count = 0
     gci $dir1 -name | foreach {
        $fname = $_
       if ($files -notcontains $fname) {
          echo "not found: $fname" 
          $count +=1 }
       } 
    $count
```

Comment: How many files are we talking about here? And when do you consider two files equivalent? By name? Size? File hash?

Comment: 4-500 file. I simply need them to be present in name.  Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only compare the file names, use the `-Name` parameter to avoid extra unnecessary output:

```
$names = Get-ChildItem $dir1 -Name
```

You could use a hashtable to store the file names of the first set of files. Key lookups against a hashtable is waaaaaay faster than iterating (twice) through a collection:

```
$names = Get-ChildItem $dir1 -Name |% {$ht = @{}} {$ht[$_]=1} {return $ht}
```

Now you can go through the second set of files, this time using the `ContainsKey()` method on the hashtable instead of the `-contains` operator:

```
$Duplicates = Get-ChildItem $dir2 -Name |Where-Object {$ht.ContainsKey($_)}
```

Although I have to say this feels like a premature optimization for a few hundred files

Comment: I agree it may be an early optimization.  Mostly it is a chance to learn.  If I restrict the collection to filenames, why doesn't a simply -contains find the file?

Comment: -contains will work just fine, but you asked for a "speedy" way, and hashtable lookup will be faster

Comment: Speedy compared to running a GCI on individual files :-). Using `gci -name` was the trick!  It returns back an array of strings instead an array of file objects that I get when I use `|select name`. Now contains works and is obvious.  Will add updated code to my question.